# Eclipse crashing on boot (Mac)

Tags: java, eclipse, macos

I am having issues opening Eclipse on my Mac. There is no loading screen, it just crashes instantly after it is booted. Is anyone able to trace the path? This is my first time using Eclipse, so I am not very experienced.

The basic crash log (Shortened):

```
Process:               eclipse [1371]
Path:                  /Users/USER/Desktop/Eclipse.app/Contents/MacOS/eclipse
Identifier:            org.eclipse.platform.ide
Version:               4.4.2 (4.4.2.M20150204-1700)
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           eclipse [1371]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2015-06-12 19:00:02.778 +0100
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.10.3 (14D136)
Report Version:        11
Anonymous UUID:        *********************


Time Awake Since Boot: 9700 seconds

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes:       KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x000000000000003c
```

The full log can be found [**here**](http://paste.jcol.es/TcYL).
Any help is appreciated. Have a great day folks. :)

Comment: Eclipse 4.4.2 works fine for me on Mac OS X 10.10.3 using Java JDK 1.8.0 update 45

Comment: Eclipse has worked well for me in several versions, including 4.5. Then, when I tried to restart after having updated several plugins, Eclipse failed with exactly this Exception Type and Exception Code.

Answer (score 0):

There are several solutions for you. You could dual boot windows and install Eclipse and then see if it works. Or you could try other IDEs for example if you are using Eclipse to develop android apps then you could try Android Studio. Or if you are doing java applications then you could try Intellij IDEA.